# Why does FxCop flag GC.KeepAlive() as a violation?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, fxcop

what is so bad about GC.KeepAlive() that FxCop flags this as a violation?

Comment: @HansPassant: What does it mean to be smarter than an API? And why do I have to outsmart some technology in order to call an API function [that has a well-understood purpose (described here by Eric Lippert)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8713997/33225)? I am uncomfortable with your implication that merely asking a (reasonable) question is an indication of lack of smarts.

Comment: You're shooting the messenger again.  I didn't write FxCop nor am I responsible for the choices made by its designers.

Comment: @HansPassant: I was entirely referring to your comment above, and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because it's considered bad practice to be calling it, just like it's a generally a bad idea to call `GC.Collect` -- it has generally negative consequences on the collector and/or is a possible indication of a design flaw on your end.

You should be able to reconfigured FxCop to not consider calls to the method a problem if you need to call it, however. There are valid reasons to do so, after all.

Comment: Unsafe code is not a "generally bad practice", and various framework classes (say, WPF's `WriteableBitmap`) expose unmanaged pointers. If the pointer is the only thing I keep a reference to, I'd better use `GC.KeepAlive` or bad things will happen.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that GC.KeepAlive is particularly bad, but rather that it's not necessary if you convert to SafeHandle usage, and you *really, really* ought to convert to SafeHandle usage.  If you're not sure why, you might want to consider taking a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/16/396900.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/06/23/644343.aspx.

Comment: There are cases where I don't think a SafeHandle will work terribly well.  For example, an object which receives events from a long-lived object won't be usefully finalizable; a solution is to have users of the object hold references to a finalizable wrapper, which in turn holds a reference to the main object.  Finalization of the wrapper triggers cleanup of the object.  In a case like that, the wrapped calls will need GC.KeepAlive() and I'm not sure how a SafeHandle would avoid that.

Comment: It sounds like your proposed approach would touch managed objects in a finalizer.  This is not a good idea for reasons described at  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddae83kx.aspx.  There are other approaches available for avoiding resource leaks when subscribing to events on long-lived publishers.

Comment: This is not always possible. There's a second scenario you're forgetting: a non-interop purely-C# but unsafe code, like taking the back buffer of a bitmap and reading from it directly. This can warrant a `KeepAlive`.

Comment: @romkyns: The question is not about general KeepAlive usage, but rather about the FxCop rule RemoveCallsToGCKeepAlive, which is specifically intended to detect potential cases where a SafeHandle should probably be used in place of a finalizer.