# Is GC.KeepAlive required here, or can I rely on locals and arguments keeping an object alive?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, unsafe

I have a bunch of methods that take the WPF's `WriteableBitmap` and read from its `BackBuffer` directly, using unsafe code.

It's not entirely clear whether I should use `GC.KeepAlive` whenever I do something like this:

```
int MyMethod(WriteableBitmap bmp)
{
    return DoUnsafeWork(bmp.BackBuffer);
}
```

On the one hand, there remains a reference to `bmp` on `MyMethod`'s stack. On the other, it seems like relying on implementation detail - this could compile to a tail call, for example, keeping no reference to `bmp` the moment `DoUnsafeWork` is entered.

Similarly, imagine the following hypothetical code:

```
int MyMethod()
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp1 = getABitmap();
    var ptr = bmp.BackBuffer;
    WriteableBitmap bmp2 = getABitmap();
    return DoUnsafeWork(ptr, bmp2);
}
```

In theory, a reference to `bmp1` remains on the stack until the method returns, but again, it seems like using an implementation detail. Surely the compiler is free to merge `bmp1` and `bmp2` because they're never live at the same time, and even if the compiler never does that surely the JITter still can, and probably does (e.g. by storing them both in the same register, first one, then the other).

So, in general: should I rely on locals/arguments being valid references to an object, or should I always use `GC.KeepAlive` to guarantee correctness?

This is especially puzzling since, apparently, [FxCop thinks GC.KeepAlive is always bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661868/why-does-fxcop-flag-gc-keepalive-as-a-violation).

Comment: Related reading: [When do I need to use `GC.KeepAlive`?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/13/10049634.aspx) and [When does an object become available for garbage collection?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx) from Raymond Chen's blog.

Comment: @DanielPryden Excellent link; I googled up the first one but not the second one prior to asking. In addition to what I've already asked, it explains that `this` doesn't keep the current object alive either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Should I rely on locals/arguments being valid references to an object?

No. Your analysis is correct; the jitter is entirely within its rights to tell the garbage collector that the contents of the local are dead the moment they are no longer in use by managed code.

> should I always use GC.KeepAlive to guarantee correctness?

Yes. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have called WriteableBitmap.Lock before getting the back buffer then the WriteableBitmap should be pinned and underlying memory will not be moved. At least that's my interpretation of the WriteableBitmapAPI.

I have used WriteableBitmap extensively, in particular the open source WriteableBitmapEx library on codeplex (disclosure, I have contributed once to this library but its not my project). This uses the pattern of Lock / Access Backbuffer (repeatedly) / unlock / Invalidate to draw. I've never had a problem with this pattern even though the backbuffer IntPtr is stored in a struct and passed around the application.

Best regards,

Comment: I knew Lock/Unlock would come up, and I might be being naughty to not lock it while reading (the documentation only explains why you should lock while writing). However, this has nothing to do with fixing the pointer; `BackBuffer` is guaranteed to be fixed, as per MSDN.

Comment: Hmm, didnt know that, thanks! I'll do some tests on my own code as Lock/Unlock is an expensive operation :)

Regarding your question, I've seen GC do some odd things like collect things still in scope but no longer used, specifically in release mode. Do you get different results in Release or Debug with your code example?

Comment: The question is theoretical; I haven't seen any actual misbehaviour with this type of code yet. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if it happens to always work on the current compiler/JIT.

Comment: I have. I had a unit test once that collected a reference because below the cursor it was no longer in scope (although still at the same scope block). The build server always compiled release mode whereas developers tested in debug, so it failed occasionally (and I mean really intermittent) on the server, but never failed on the local box! GC.KeepAlive(ref) in this specific case was needed